# Why Iron Router function doesn't redirect?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Using FS.Collection to store files, I need to redirect to currently submitted file, but I can't get Iron Router working. It returns result._id, but don't route and just breaks.

Here is the event change function for submitting files.

```js
'change #input':function(event, template){
    var email = template.find('#email').value;
    var title = template.find('#booktitle').value;
    if (email != '' && title != '') {
      // Get value
      var file = $('#input').get(0).files[0]
          
          fsFile = new FS.File(file);
          //Metadata
          fsFile.metadata = {
            title:title,
            email:email
           } 
      Books.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
          if(!err){
             console.log(result._id);
             Router.go('sumarize', {_id:result._id});
           }
      })
    } else {
      alert("Insert your email address, please.")
    }
  }
```

And Iron Router function :

```js
Router.route('/summarize/:_id', {
 name: 'summarize',
 data: function() { return Books.findOne(this.params._id);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Router.go` call:

```
Router.go('summarize', {_id:result._id});
```

Comment: No worries. Yeah truth hurts sometimes... Good luck in your coding!